# compilation is not happening on page refresh in GWT Super Dev Mode

Tags: java, maven, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I have multiple maven based application developed using GWT+SmartGWT.Currently i migrated to GWT 2.7 and setup Super Dev Mode for this multiple maven project and launch the SDM.But when i referesh the page compilation is not happening.Is there anythink i need to configure.Any Suggestion?

Comment: How are you launching SDM? Through DevMode? or CodeServer? with which parameters?

Comment: with CodeServer only..Earlier i was using Dev mode ,jst added codeserver.jar ,codeserver class to my java application debugger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Compile on load" is only enabled in SDM if a `-launcherDir` is passed as argument. `CodeServer` will then generate a `*.nocache.js` that triggers "compile on load" (but requires a running `CodeServer`, so make sure you recompile your application before deploying, or use a distinct directory for SDM vs. production compilation output).

If you don't pass `-launcherDir`, then you're back to the legacy (and deprecated) SDM that uses bookmarklets and `sessionStorage`.

Comment: thanks thomas for your quick response..I will try this and let u know

Comment: Thomas still the same problem is exist.But in standalone while refreshing its compiling the apps.even i passed -launcherDir argument ,compilation is not happening.any suggestion

Comment: What value are you using for `-launcherDir`?

Comment: -launcherDir D:\gwtTemp\Application adding this to the argument

Comment: If the `*.nocache.js` file generated by the `CodeServer` in there is not loaded by your browser, of course you won't get the "compile on load" feature. `-launcherDir` must be a directory that's served by your web server (not necessarily the one of your webapp if you use "overlays", but the generated file should be available through HTTP at the exact same place you'd expect the `*.nocache.js` file in production)

Comment: Thanks Thomas..I am able to solve this issue..(+1)..added -launcherDir webserver path.